# Unable to hide Products.Carousel.viewlet in version 1.1

Tags: plone, genericsetup, viewlets

Products,Carousel adds a viewlet to the `plone.contentviews` manager using some funky inline code in setuphandlers. I am trying to hide this viewlet. I have tried various techniques such as:

- overriding the template in my `configure.zcml`
- using the `<hidden>` tag in my `viewlets.xml`

But nothing seems to take effect. However if I go into `@@manage-viewlets`, I am able to hide it by hand.

How can i do this automatically on startup?

Comment: Both of the techniques you mentioned should work. Can you show us the code you tried?

Comment: I guess this is a bug, I have the same issue with collective.disqus add-on on Plone4, the plone comment viewlet is not hidden by the default profile of this add-on. Please report this on the plone bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but you could override the viewlet template using **z3c.jbot** if you're really desperate. Just provide an empty template called **Products.Carousel.browser.viewlet.pt** in your z3c.jbot templates folder, inside your custom product.